# onbeforeunload not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

In my page I have a button that opens a page and writes a piece of code in it.

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){

var x = window.open('', '', 'width=800, height=600');

x.document.open().write(something);
}
```

I want to fire a function in my parent window, to update an element when my child window is closed. I've tried so far to use:

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){

var x = window.open('', '', 'width=800, height=600');

x.onbeforeunload = function(){    
console.log('closed');    
}

x.document.open().write(something);

}
```

What I've discovered so far is that Chrome prevents me of using "onbeforeunload" or any kind of unload event.

So if anyone has an answer to how workaround this issue I'll be very appricieted.

**UPDATE**

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cgckg3zh/

I've also tested in Firefox, is working.

Comment: create fiddle if possible...

Comment: How does Chrome prevent you?  Do you get an error?  If so, please post the error message.

Comment: In fact, it does not do anything. No error, no warning, just nothing.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, this is [deprecated on Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480).

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue to fire event on closing page but eventually i realized that using event is unreliable because some browser does not support it...
finally for my project i used `signalr` to detect closing windows or navigating page...
i am sure that there is not any javascript event that is supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more straightforward approach.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return "You should keep this page open.";
});
```

The returned message can be anything you want, including the empty string if you have nothing to add to the message that Chrome already shows. The result looks like this:

[image]

Hope this help you :)

Comment: The problem is thar I need to do stuff in the parent when the child window closes.

I don't see how this can help me.

Comment: did u try =>   x.onunload = function(){    
console.log('closed');    
}

Comment: Yes, and get me nothing, neither alert or console.log